# PHP date() print 24:00 instead of 00:00

Tags: php, date

PHP `date("H:i (d.m.Y)",$timestamp)` function represents exact midnight as 00:00 of following day. But I need it to represent it as 24:00 of preceding day. Is it possible to be done without writing completely new date() parser function?

**edit:** Why do I need such 'weird' format? Because my client demands it. In my country (CZ), 24:00 is sometimes used when referring to exact midnight.

**edit2:** My current 'dirty' solution is: (does not work with all possible format strings)

```
function date_24midnight($format,$ts)
{
   if(date("Hi",$ts)=="0000")
      return preg_replace('/23:59/',"24:00",date($format,$ts-1));
   else
      return date($format,$ts);
}
```

Comment: There is no such time as `24:00`. In what situation would you tell someone it is `24:00` hours?

Comment: Here in Portugal is used a lot. Maybe an European thing :)

Comment: I do not think it is a european thing (living in london) having a time like 24:00 kinda programatically implies you might have 24:01 aswell which is totally wrong

Comment: If 00:00 is the only time that needs to be presented differently just us a condition: `if (time == "00:00") time = "24:00";`

Comment: @Lucius you would also need to correct the day as 00:00 is the start of the day where as 24:00 is the end of the day

Comment: Beware if you need to use this value on SQL. I think it won't accept as valid date. If just for display, use Lucius solution.

Comment: Just for completeness: according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), _24:00_ may be used to refer to midnight (i.e. _0:00_) of the following day. Times such as 24:01 etc. are invalid.

Comment: Why do I need such 'weird' format? Because my client demands it. In my country (CZ), 24:00 is sometimes used when referring to exact midnight.

Comment: Your solution is fine and a good answer for your own question.

Comment: Well in Japan they schedule shows on TV and/or radio at 25:00 till 27:00 http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090207184509AA5Ci56

Comment: As stated in the comments, what you've done is fine. There's no "native" date format that will display 00:00 as 24:00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function date_24midnight($format,$ts)
{
   if(date("Hi",$ts)=="0000") {
      $replace = array(
        "H" => "24",
        "G" => "24",
        "i" => "00",
      );

      return date(
        str_replace(
          array_keys($replace),
          $replace, 
          $format
        ),
        $ts-60 // take a full minute off, not just 1 second
      );
   } else {
      return date($format,$ts);
   }
}
```

This function is based on yours, But works for all formats (that I tested)

So `H:i:s` works for example

It will need some extra work to for for formats like `"\H\i Y-m-d"`